# How to wrap Carousel.Item in other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am working in this `react-bootstrap` carousel. Current code is working well:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <Carousel>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            className="d-block w-100"
            src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tpostr/image/upload/v1553865338/paparouna/IMG_7638-01.jpg"
            alt="First slide"
          />
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            className="d-block w-100"
            src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tpostr/image/upload/v1553865338/paparouna/IMG_7638-01.jpg"
            alt="First slide"
          />
        </Carousel.Item>
      </Carousel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Demo working well](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactbootstrapcarousel-forked-e5uj6?file=/src/index.js)

Now Im **trying to separate `Carousel.Item` to other component**, so I can use it without repeating myself. But **the image doesnt appear**:

```
const CarouselItem = () => (
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tpostr/image/upload/v1553865338/paparouna/IMG_7638-01.jpg"
      alt="First slide"
    />
  </Carousel.Item>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <Carousel>
        <CarouselItem />
        <CarouselItem />
      </Carousel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Demo with error](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactbootstrapcarousel-forked-05i2z?file=/src/index.js)

I have tried wrapping the component with `forwardRef`, but didnt work. What Im doing wrong? Note: I need `CarouselItem` to be a component/function in order to be able to send props to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you render the `Carousel.Item` in a separate component, you need to forward the props to it.

Internally `Carousel` will be using `React.cloneElement` to add extra props to the `Carousel.Item` which when you use a custom component need to forward to `Carousel.Item`

```
const CarouselItem = (props) => (
  <Carousel.Item {...props}>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tpostr/image/upload/v1553865338/paparouna/IMG_7638-01.jpg"
      alt="First slide"
    />
  </Carousel.Item>
);
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactbootstrapcarousel-forked-yccb3)

Comment: Didn't know about compound components. Cool answer. Also the source code for seeing `cloneElement` in action - https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/v1.0.0-beta.8/src/Carousel.js.  Also the version in `codesandbox` seems to a beta-version and I have shared the link according to it. I think the OP should also be using the latest one i.e. 1.5.2.