# Bootstrap Carousel Image doesn't show

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I try to make carousel parts as components to make it organized but the images of carousel doesn't exist in carousel even the image src is correct. I made the carousel in file called `Panner.js` and Carousel Item in separated file called `CarouselItemChild.js` I pass the `src`, `Carousel`, `label` and `description` as props in `CarouselItemChild`

`Panner.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Carousel } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Panner.css';
import first from '../assets/blue/20210609_172157.jpg';
import second from '../assets/gray/20210612_154438.jpg';
import third from '../assets/pink/20210511_174415.jpg';
import CarouselItemChild from './CarouselItem/CarouselItemChild';
const Panner = () => {
return (
    <Carousel className="panner">
        <CarouselItemChild
            Carousel={Carousel}
            src={first}
            label={'blue silk scarf'}
            description={
                'description blue silk scarf description blue silk scarf description blue silk scarf'
            }
        />
        {/* <img src={first} alt="" srcset="" /> */}
    </Carousel>
);
   };

 export default Panner;
```

`CarouselItemChild`

```
import React from 'react';

const CarouselItemChild = ({ Carousel, src, label, description }) => {
return (
    <Carousel.Item interval={1000}>
        <img className="d-block w-100" src={src} alt="a slider" />
        <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>{label}</h3>
            <p>{description}</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
);
};

export default CarouselItemChild;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wrap Carousel.Item in other component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66987354/how-to-wrap-carousel-item-in-other-component)

Comment: Why do you pass `Carousel` as a property and not import it in `CarouselItemChild` ?